# Find my darcula theme/scheme file in finder

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, themes

Since I am using two different Macs (work-home), I want to bring my configured Darcula theme/scheme from my home laptop, to my office's Mac and be able to select it from here:

[image]

Tried to find where this file is located in my finder, but it seems that I can't find it.

Anyone know where that file is, or what files do I need to grab for my office Android Studio to look the same as the one at home (including font/colours etc.), including their location outside Android Studio?

Seems that there is no such question out there, compared on how to do this with Xcode!

Answer (score 1):

After saving colors and your theme schema choose `File -> Export Settings...` and leave all options checked.

I believe that `Look and Feel` option is about theme you're actually using.

Now you have a `.jar` file with all settings, including theme and colors. Import it using `File -> Import Settings`.

> NOTE: if you're using a GitHub, the best way to share your preferences between computers is creating `Settings Repository` and import it with IntelliJ /Android Studio. Both operations - creating and importing you would do in your IDE.
>
> Please check how to do it: [Sharing Your IDE Settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/sharing-your-ide-settings.html)

It should work.

Comment: sometimes we look for a more complicated solution to deal with something...thanks a lot will test it later on today and mark this as the answer if it does the job!